# Entering data in multiple tables using foreign key constraints

Tags: mysql, insert

I have following data:

```
Array
(
    [teacher_street] => Okhla
    [teacher_city] => Delhi
    [teacher_state] => National Capital Territory of Delhi
    [teacher_pin] => 110025
)
```

I need to insert the above data into a table called address:

```
CREATE TABLE `address` (
  `address_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `address_street` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `state_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `address_pin` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Now, I need to insert city and state in city table and state table first, if they don't exist. If they exist, I need to get primary keys corresponding to them:

```
CREATE TABLE `city` (
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `state` (
  `state_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `state_name` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

After that I need to get the corresponding primary keys and need to put in first table. How can I achieve the same in one go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your city and state tables appear to have no AUTO_INCREMENT primary keys. You would have to specify the value as you insert into these tables.

If so, then your application code has the value it just inserted, and you can use it as you insert to the address table.

If you do in fact use AUTO_INCREMENT primary keys, you'll have to query `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to fetch the id after you insert to the city and state tables, and use these as you insert to the address table. Or else if you don't want to do that, query the id by searching for city name or state name before you insert to address.

Comment: So basically I need to to following tasks:
`1. Select from city table/Insert in city table get the key
2. Select from state table/Insert in state table get the key
3. Insert into address table.`

Comment: Correct. But it's still not clear to me if you're using AUTO_INCREMENT or not. Your code above shows you aren't, but your description of the steps suggests you think you are.

Comment: Yes. I will be using AUTO_INCREMENT. A few things more, can I rely on last_insert_id(), if a lot of insert happening at a given time? Also, do I need to use transaction, assuming whole insertion process might fail at a given time?

Comment: What do you mean rely on? It returns the most recent auto-inc id generated in your session, regardless of what other sessions are doing. Read more about it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: As for transactions, yes, if you want to insert to three tables and commit these three inserts atomically, you should use a transaction. I can't tell from your description if that's what you want.